# Estimation of correlation?

Tags: probability, statistics, computational-mathematics

Given a huge data matrix $X$ with many columns, it would be expensive to exactly compute its correlation matrix. Anyone knows any existing method or algorithms to roughly estimate the correlation matrix, and help provide some reference?

Comment: How much is the size of columns and rows each?

Comment: Cursury searching provides [this link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.163.2245&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Generically, what you want is an _approximation algorithm_, so searching something like "approximation algorithm for correlation matrix computation" will be useful.

Comment: "Matrix sketching" may also be useful for this problem.